# Scala reduce and fold returns 0 instead of a value

Tags: java, scala, reduce, scala-collections, fold

Hey I have a case where I tried to run this on REPL:

```
(1 to 100).toList.reduce(_*_)
```

And it Returned me 0. I did not understand this behavior. If the Int has been overflowed it should have returned any negative or positive number. I got curious hence I tried this:

```
(1 to 100).toList.fold(1)(_*_)
```

It still returned me 0
Then I tried this:

```
(1 to 100).toList.fold(1)((a,b) => { println(s"dd::::$a:::$b"); a*b })
```

It returns me :

```
scala> res0.toList.fold(1)((a,b) => { println(s"dd::::$a:::$b"); a*b })
dd::::1:::1
dd::::1:::2
dd::::2:::3
dd::::6:::4
dd::::24:::5
dd::::120:::6
dd::::720:::7
dd::::5040:::8
dd::::40320:::9
dd::::362880:::10
dd::::3628800:::11
dd::::39916800:::12
dd::::479001600:::13
dd::::1932053504:::14
dd::::1278945280:::15
dd::::2004310016:::16
dd::::2004189184:::17
dd::::-288522240:::18
dd::::-898433024:::19
dd::::109641728:::20
dd::::-2102132736:::21
dd::::-1195114496:::22
dd::::-522715136:::23
dd::::862453760:::24
dd::::-775946240:::25
dd::::2076180480:::26
dd::::-1853882368:::27
dd::::1484783616:::28
dd::::-1375731712:::29
dd::::-1241513984:::30
dd::::1409286144:::31
dd::::738197504:::32
dd::::-2147483648:::33
dd::::-2147483648:::34
dd::::0:::35
dd::::0:::36
dd::::0:::37
dd::::0:::38
dd::::0:::39
dd::::0:::40
dd::::0:::41
dd::::0:::42
dd::::0:::43
dd::::0:::44
dd::::0:::45
dd::::0:::46
dd::::0:::47
dd::::0:::48
dd::::0:::49
dd::::0:::50
dd::::0:::51
dd::::0:::52
dd::::0:::53
dd::::0:::54
dd::::0:::55
dd::::0:::56
dd::::0:::57
dd::::0:::58
dd::::0:::59
dd::::0:::60
dd::::0:::61
dd::::0:::62
dd::::0:::63
dd::::0:::64
dd::::0:::65
dd::::0:::66
dd::::0:::67
dd::::0:::68
dd::::0:::69
dd::::0:::70
dd::::0:::71
dd::::0:::72
dd::::0:::73
dd::::0:::74
dd::::0:::75
dd::::0:::76
dd::::0:::77
dd::::0:::78
dd::::0:::79
dd::::0:::80
dd::::0:::81
dd::::0:::82
dd::::0:::83
dd::::0:::84
dd::::0:::85
dd::::0:::86
dd::::0:::87
dd::::0:::88
dd::::0:::89
dd::::0:::90
dd::::0:::91
dd::::0:::92
dd::::0:::93
dd::::0:::94
dd::::0:::95
dd::::0:::96
dd::::0:::97
dd::::0:::98
dd::::0:::99
dd::::0:::100
res5: Int = 0
```

I do not understand this behavior clearly. Could anyone please help !Thanks

Comment: What about integer overflow?

Comment: "If the Int has been overflowed it should have returned any negative or positive number." Why did you think it _couldn't_ return 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not understand this behavior clearly

Generally, what you're experiencing is [*arithmetic overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow). If you want to pinpoint exactly why the 34th value returns 0, then doing the calculation by hand can help.

The result of the 33th product is `-2147483648`, which is:

```
64bit hex: 0x‭FFFFFFFF80000000‬
32bit hex: 0x80000000

64bit binary: ‭1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000‬
32bit binary: 10000000000000000000000000000000
```

We multiply it by 34, we get:

```
64bit hex: ‭0xFFFFFFEF00000000‬
32bit hex: 0x00000000‬

64bit binary: ‭1111111111111111111111111110111100000000000000000000000000000000‬
32bit binary: 00000000000000000000000000000000‬
```

Since `Int` looks at the lower 32bit, you get `0`. Everything on from here will result in `0` since that's the accumulators value and you're doing multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following to understand what is going on:

```
val x = Int.MinValue
x - 1 // = Int.MaxValue-1
x + x // = 0
x + x + x // = Int.MinValue
```

When you subtract from Int.MinValue you start from the max value. If you subtract abs(MinValue) from MinValue (MinValue * 2) you will be doing abs(MinValue) steps left from MaxValue which will bring you to 0.

This behaviour leads you to a situation in which MinValue * even number = 0 and MinValue * odd number = MinValue

Both behaviours occurred on lines 33-34, and of course as soon as one of you results is 0, all of your other results will be 0 as well.

Answer (score 3):

In your output there is one line like: `dd::::-2147483648:::34`, which produces `0` as output. Hence all subsequent multiplications result in `0`.

Reason being `-2147483648` in minimum value of `Int` (`Int.MinValue`).

```
scala> Int.MinValue
res6: Int = -2147483648
```

If you try `-2147483648 + -2147483648` in REPL, because of `Int` overflow, output will be `0`. Now when you do `-2147483648 * 34` it is equivalent to `(-2147483648 + (-2147483648)) * 17`, hence output is `0`.